# Is it possible to find the area under some curves (such as $\sin x$ and $x^2$) without using knowledge of calculus (or above)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area, alternative-proof

Is there any elementary method (i.e., a method only using precalculs) to find the exact value of the area under certain curve, say $x^2$ between $x=0$ and $x=2$?

Comment: Riemann sums? Make some approximations?

Comment: [The Quadrature of the Parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quadrature_of_the_Parabola) was written by Archimedes over two thousand years ago and uses geometry and geometric series to calculate various areas.

Comment: @AndrewChin First thing that came to my mind, too.